# How to get Fiverr jobs at the beginning

Tags: contracts, price, portfolio, marketing

I have been using Fiverr for one month, but I did not make lots of orders up to now. I think I should improve my gig with some attractive way for the users, so what are the key things that can be used to improve my gig to get more jobs?

How should I make the pricing and what kind of keywords should I use and what kind of images should be in the gallery?

Comment: There are plenty of facebook groups related to freelancing and especially for Fiverr. You can share your gig there in different groups. Also, to your social networking sites.

Answer (score 7):

As a beginner, try to keep your **prices low**, but not so low that it gives off an image of low quality. Add all the **keywords** that are relevant to your services. Also, along with keeping your **images and description clear yet catchy**, try adding proofs of your capabilities. For this, [Fiverr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiverr) allows you to take **tests** for different domains. You can also add **certifications**, if any.

Like other freelancing websites, Fiverr has now also given the option of bidding, called **buyer requests**. In this way, you can look for a job that you think is appropriate for you and apply for it, rather than waiting for the buyers to come to you. You can find the complete details [here](https://sellers.fiverr.com/en/article/submitting-offers-to-buyer-requests).

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a nice Profile, with a professional profile image, focused description.
2. Create Attractive gig. With a nice gig image, proper gig descriptions. Add previous work samples. Add gig tags related to your service.
3. At the beginning try to offer small/split services.
4. Stay online, maximum time that is possible.
5. You can try Buyer Request. But for the new updates, BR job posts are limited for sellers without any level.